# Как лучше получить модель Django, зная ее название?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

У меня есть **2 файла с моделями**. Пусть будет `models_a` и `models_b`. И есть функция, которая выполняет похожие действия с этими моделями. Поэтому функция на все модели одна. К какой именно модели нужно применить эти действия, я узнаю по названию модели, которое попадает в функцию в виде строки. И мне нужно по этому названию получить нужную модель. Я сделал это вот так

```py
from models_a import *
from models_b import *

def my_func(model_name):
    model = globals().get(model_name)
    qs = model.objects.all()
```

В принципе, это работает. Подскажите - сильно ли плох этот вариант? Как эффективнее можно решить такую задачу?

Comment: Зачем globals использовать? Можно саму модель в качестве аргумента передать вроде как.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич ну, может и можно, но мне этот вариант не подходит. Мне нужно получить модель по ее названию.

Comment: Ничего плохого в этом варианте нет. А учитывая, что он не использует "приватные" методы языка - очевидно, что данная реализация близка к рекомендуемой под Вашу задачу.

Comment: Где то в исходниках самой Django видел подобные конструкции, это признак "правильности" имхо :)

Comment: Есть метод `get_model` для этого.

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 given app_label and model_name. Я заранее не знаю app_label, это файлики из 2х разных приложений.

Comment: А почему бы не передавать `app_name` в урлах?

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 ок, но возникает тогда вопрос - а чем так плохо взять из globals()? :)

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров плохо, что вы не используете встроенный метод  Джанги, а изобретаете  свой велосипед.

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 тут я не могу не согласиться :) Ок, спасибо за наводку, надо подумать как это лучше сделать теперь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Способ 1**

```
import sys

from django.apps import apps


def my_func(request, model_name):
    Model = apps.get_model(app_label=sys.modules[resolve(request.path_info).func.__module__].__package__, model_name=model_name)
```

**Способ 2** - работает намного быстрее и является предпочтительным.

1. Добавить в `<app>.urls.py` строку

```
app_name='<app_name>'
```

2. В функции

```
from django.apps import apps


def my_func(request, model_name):
    Model = apps.get_model(request.resolver_match.app_name, model_name)
```

---

Проверил Ваш метод. Он работает быстрее всего, но [что-то мне подсказывает](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil), что это не самое лучшее решение.

Comment: ____module__.__package__ не есть хороший стиль.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич поэтому я и советую второй вариант.

Comment: вроде как apps.get_model работает через то же global() внутри, а ввиду того, что это еще дополнительный вызов - не факт, что такой код оптимальнее того, что в вопросе в части производительности.

Comment: Вроде как, `apps.get_model` не работает через `global()` - https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/apps/config.py#L167